# How do you make the background of a wxPython window a bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, grid, wxpython

I have successfully made a python twitter client but it is run in wxPython for a GUI. I need to know how to set the background image of the windows. The windows ISN'T re-sizable and and the image is a bitmap. Please help. I don't NEED this but I want it for aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on that a while back. Check it out: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

Comment: This gives me a bunch of errors when I do this. AND I changed the name of the picture just so you know.

Comment: I know several other people have used this method and it has worked. Maybe if you shared the errors along with your OS, wx and Python version, we could figure it out. Seeing a small runnable example would be nice too.

Comment: I would rather not. I will just deal with it for now and do a bit of research.